# How to stop Touch or Click Event while Swipe Event is in action in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, swipe, touch-event

In my code i use both swipe gesture and click event at the same time. How to avoid click event or touch event while swipe gesture is in action?

```
stage.addEventListener (TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, fl_SwipeHandler);
wall.tile[0].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showBook());
wall.tile[1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showBook());

 public function fl_SwipeHandler(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
   {
     switch(event.offsetY)
     {
        // swiped down
        case 1:
        {
        if (swipe!=0){
             Tweener.addTween(wall, {y: wall.y + 650, time:.5, transition:"easeOutSine" } );
             swipe--;
             }
        // End your custom code
        break;
        }
        // swiped up
        case -1:
        {
        if (swipe<=(total/5)){
             Tweener.addTween(wall, { y: wall.y - 650, time:.5, transition:"easeOutSine" } );
             swipe++;
             }
        // End your custom code
        break;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I even used Stoppropogation() and useCapture, priority

stage.addEventListener (TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, fl_SwipeHandler, true, 1);
tile.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showBook, false, -1);

public function showBook(MouseEvent):void
  {
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually have some boolean variable set to true when swipe is being activated, and onComplete function of tweener sets it back to false. And that boolean is one condition in my onClick functions (as false obviously):

```
public var swipeOn:Boolean;

public function fl_SwipeHandler(event:TransformGestureEvent):void{
     switch(event.offsetY){
        case 1:{
            if (swipe!=0){
                swipeOn = true;
                Tweener.addTween(wall, {y: wall.y + 650, time:.5, transition:"easeOutSine", onComplete:doneSwipe } );
                swipe--;
            }
            break;
        }

        case -1:{
            if(swipe<=(total/5)){
                swipeOn = true;
                Tweener.addTween(wall, { y: wall.y - 650, time:.5, transition:"easeOutSine", onComplete:doneSwipe } );
                swipe++;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

public function doneSwipe():void{
    swipeOn = false;
}

public function showBook(Event:MouseEvent):void{
    if(!swipeOn){
        //....handle your clicks etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer dude. But i added one code inside the **function fl_SwipeHandler()** that is, 'swipeOn = true;'

Comment: Can you answer me one more question? Actually **showbook()** opens a starling, when we come to the main screen after **starling.dispose()** TransformGestureEvent is not working. I even used **stage.removeEventListener (TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, fl_SwipeHandler);** inside **showbook()**